# Golang form to download a local file in the

Tags: html, go

I have a simple webpage rendered with Golang. After successful submit of the web form, I m returning a Download link to a localfile that was created with the program.

When I download, I m getting the html form in the downloaded file. I have tried different approaches and still am not successful.

```html
{{if .Success}}
    <h1>Request submitted successfully</h1>
    <a href="img.jpeg" download>
        download
    </a> I have tried different ways like, using file://img.jpeg, relative path etc
    <!-- <a href="filresponse.md" download="response.md">Download the markdown!</a> -->
{{else}}
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        <label>Email:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="email"><br />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
{{end}}
```

Based on the comments, I changed my main as following

```html
func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("method:", r.Method) //get request method
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("forms.html")
        t.Execute(w, nil)
    } 
  else {
        generateMD(r.FormValue("email"))
        r.ParseForm()
        fmt.Println("contentID:", r.FormValue("email"))
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/login", login)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func generateMD(contentID string) {
    var confContent confluence.Content
    confContent.ID = contentID
    bodyrequest := confluence.ConfPageContent(confContent.ID)
    json.Unmarshal(bodyrequest, &confContent)
    title := "# " + confContent.Title + "\n"
    formatted_html := regex.Regex(confContent.Body.Storage.Value)
    markdown := custom_md.Format(formatted_html)
    f, _ := os.OpenFile("response.md", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    f.WriteString(title)
    f.WriteString(markdown)
}
```

What should I add to get the file to be downloadable?

EDIT: changed Go part HTTP function

Comment: When the download link is clicked, it will send a GET request with that link. You have to handle GET for /img.jpeg, read the file and return its contents.

Comment: I have changed my code to have a GET and POST. But I cant get to return to a GET after my POST is successful. I will update my question with the changes I made

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working, but not with the HTML form (I m still trying to get this working as well)

```html
func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("method:", r.Method) //get request method
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("forms.html")
        t.Execute(w, nil)
    } else {
        fileName := generateMD(r.FormValue("confluence"))
        // Set headers for the file download.
        w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
        // Open and read the file content.
        fileContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "Failed to read the file", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        // Write the file content to the HTTP response.
        _, err = w.Write(fileContent)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "Failed to write the file content to the response", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

This login function would download the file once the function generateMD is called.